# How can I "require('web3')" on Amazon AWS Lambda?

Tags: web3js, aws

If I understand the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) correctly, I need to *build* web3.js on AWS Lambda. How can I do that and which version should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Just `npm install web3` locally. On my Mac machine the only issue then was the building of the scrypt package. You can add an install script to your `package.json` to build it locally:

```
"install": "[ -e node_modules/scrypt/build/Release/scrypt.node ] || docker run --rm -v $PWD:/data -w /data node:6 npm install scrypt"
```

Note: You need docker installed. Solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487001/5887673.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having issues with running web3 > 1.0.0 and you're using SAM local to test it, consider running `sam build --use-container` prior to executing the lambda with `sam invoke local` .

This will build and install any dependencies inside of a amazon linux container instead of building it locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking to build web3 on aws lambda, use a combination of serverless framework, serverless-plugin-scripts and docker to prebuild the node modules before deploying, more details here: [web3 serverless](https://coderecipe.ai/architectures/57148351)